# Add missing index in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi I have a messy data frame as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(age.band = c("0-5","5-10"), beg.code = c("A1","B1"), end.code=c("A5","B3"),value = c(10,5))

age.band beg.code end.code  value
   0-5      A1      A5        10
   5-10     B1      B3         5
```

I would like to transform it into a friendlier format such as:

```
   index    age.band   value
     A1         0-5        10
     A2         0-5        10
     A3         0-5        10
     A4         0-5        10
     A5         0-5        10
     B1         5-10        5
     B2         5-10        5
     B3         5-10        5
```

Can anyone help me to find a way to add all the missing indexes for this dataframe? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr). Nptice that I added `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to avoid creating factor columns when creating your example data frame. If you run the code on your original data frame, you will receive warning message due to the factor columns, but it will not affect the end results.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  gather(Code, Value, ends_with("code")) %>%
  extract(Value, into = c("Group", "Index"), regex = "([A-Za-z+].*)([\\d].*$)",
          convert = TRUE) %>%
  select(-Code) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  complete(Index = full_seq(Index, period = 1)) %>%
  unite(Index, c("Group", "Index"), sep = "") %>%
  fill(-Index)
df2
# # A tibble: 8 x 3
#   Index age.band value
# * <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
# 1    A1      0-5    10
# 2    A2      0-5    10
# 3    A3      0-5    10
# 4    A4      0-5    10
# 5    A5      0-5    10
# 6    B1     5-10     5
# 7    B2     5-10     5
# 8    B3     5-10     5
```

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(age.band = c("0-5","5-10"), beg.code = c("A1","B1"), end.code=c("A5","B3"),value = c(10,5),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `base R`.  The idea is to remove the non-numeric characters from the 'code' columns, convert it to `numeric` and get the sequence stored as a `list`.  Then, `paste` the non-numeric characters and finally, based on the `lengths` of the `list`, expand the rows of the original dataset with `rep` and create a new column 'index' by `unlist`ing the `list`

```
lst <- do.call(Map, c(f = `:`, lapply(df[2:3], function(x) as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", x)))))
lst1 <- Map(paste0, substr(df[,2], 1, 1), lst)
data.frame(index = unlist(lst1), df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), lengths(lst1)), -(2:3)])
```